# extract words in between two commas in R

Tags: r, regex, concatenation

I have the following string

```
word <- 'Fu Tien Mansion, Taikoo Shing, Hong Kong'
```

and I want to extract the word in between the two commas and concatenate it with the first word, what regex to use?

Desired output:

```
'Taikoo Shing Fu Tien Mansion'
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `sub` to capture substrings as a group and in the replacement use backreferences of that group

```
sub("^([^,]+),\\s*([^,]+),.*", "\\2 \\1", word)
#[1] "Taikoo Shing Fu Tien Mansion"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> x <- strsplit(word, ",")[[1]]
> paste(x[2], x[1])
[1] " Taikoo Shing Fu Tien Mansion
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sapply` with `strsplit` -

```
> paste(trimws(sapply(strsplit(word,","), `[`, 2)), trimws(sapply(strsplit(word,","), `[`, 1)))
[1] "Taikoo Shing Fu Tien Mansion"
```

Comment: That's a neat way of using `sapply(y, `[`, 2)` to excess content inside `y[[...]]` .  - Why this would be ever better than just writing `y[[1]][2]` ??

Answer (score 1):

```
sapply(word, function(w){
    ind = gregexpr(",", w)[[1]]
    paste(substring(w, ind[1] + 2, ind[2] - 1),
          substring(w, 1, ind[1] - 1))
})
#Fu Tien Mansion, Taikoo Shing, Hong Kong 
#          "Taikoo Shing Fu Tien Mansion"
```